# Slide transition scripts using jQuery or jQTouch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there step by step tutorial or drag/drop the scripts using jQuery or jqTouch for **transition slide** animation?

I've tried this and it is still not enough.
https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/Getting-Started

I'm hoping to use a strightforward template or copy/paste the scripts for **transition slide**?

It is for iphone app.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is inside the a tag state data-transition="slide"

i.e.

```
<a href="photo.html" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-theme="a"> Photo gallery </a>
```

Comment: Is that jQuery you're talking about?

Comment: I'll be using my own CSS style e.g.theme="a".